# Isomorphic Strings (the easy way?)

Tags: python

So I have been trying to solve the Easy questions on Leetcode and so far I dont understand most of the answers I find on the internet. I tried working on the Isomorphic strings problem (here:https://leetcode.com/problems/isomorphic-strings/description/)
and I came up with the following code

```
def isIso(a,b):
        if(len(a) != len(b)):
                return false
        x=[a.count(char1) for char1 in a]
        y=[b.count(char1) for char1 in b]
        return x==y                   
string1 = input("Input string1..")
string2 = input("Input string2..")
print(isIso(string1,string2))
```

Now I understand that this may be the most stupid code you have seen all day but that is kinda my point. I'd like to know why this would be wrong(and where) and how I should further develop on this.

Comment: You can use a dictionary instead?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the problem correctly, because a character can map to itself, it's just a case of seeing if the character counts for the two words are the same.

So egg and add are isomorphic as they have character counts of (1,2). Similarly paper and title have counts of (1,1,1,2).

foo and bar aren't isomorphic as the counts are (1,2) and (1,1,1) respectively.

To see if the character counts are the same we'll need to sort them.

So:

```
from collections import Counter
def is_isomorphic(a,b):
    a_counts = list(Counter(a).values())
    a_counts.sort()
    b_counts = list(Counter(b).values())
    b_counts.sort()
    if a_counts == b_counts:
        return True
    return False
```

Your code is failing because here:

```
x=[a.count(char1) for char1 in a]
```

You count the occurrence of each character in the string for each character in the string. So a word like 'odd' won't have counts of (1,2), it'll have (1,2,2) as you count d twice!

Comment: As you pointed out, odd will have counts of (1,2,2) hence representing a pattern in the word which when equal to the other can be mapped and isomorphic as far as I can see. Is there a test case you can say where I will definitely fail or if this code is in any way unconventional?

Comment: Ah, yes. You're right. Your code will just duplicate a count of `n` `n` times. So your code will work ok. While odd does not have a character count of (1,2,2) as it only has two distinct characters, it doesn't stop your code from working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two dicts to keep track of the mapping of each character in `a` to `b`, and the mapping of each character in `b` to `a` while you iterate through `a`, and if there's any violation in a corresponding character, return `False`; otherwise return `True` in the end.

```
def isIso(a, b):
    m = {} # mapping of each character in a to b
    r = {} # mapping of each character in b to a
    for i, c in enumerate(a):
        if c in m:
            if b[i] != m[c]:
                return False
        else:
            m[c] = b[i]
        if b[i] in r:
            if c != r[b[i]]:
                return False
        else:
            r[b[i]] = c
    return True
```

So that:

```
print(isIso('egg', 'add'))
print(isIso('foo', 'bar'))
print(isIso('paper', 'title'))
print(isIso('paper', 'tttle')) # to test reverse mapping
```

would output:

```
True
False
True
False
```

Comment: I like how you implemented this. Was easier for me understand. I have been working with C++ longer than Python and frankly the C++ solutions I've seen so far are unreadable. Could you think of an instance where my program would fail?

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import zip_longest
def isomorph(a, b):
    return len(set(a)) == len(set(b)) == len(set(zip_longest(a, b)))
```

here is the second way to do it:

```
def isomorph(a, b):
    return [a.index(x) for x in a] == [b.index(y) for y in b]
```

Comment: The second way to do it shows clearly how this is about matching indexes of characters in their own space.

Answer (score 1):

I tried by creating a dictionary, and it resulted in 72ms runtime.
here's my code -

```
def isIsomorphic(s: str, t: str) -> bool: 
my_dict = {}
if len(s) != len(t):
    return False
else:
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] in my_dict.keys():
            if my_dict[s[i]] == t[i]:
                pass  
            else:
                return False
        else:
            if t[i] in my_dict.values():
                return False
            else:
                my_dict[s[i]] = t[i]
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways on how to do it. Below I provided three different ways by using a dictionary, set, and string.translate.

[Here I provided three different ways how to solve Isomorphic String solution in Python.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63427456/30038)